# como seleccionar un dia en un datepicker utilizando AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

Buenas, estoy haciendo un proyecto con AngularJS 1.6 y quisiera guardar en una variable del Scope un dia determinado y que al ir a la vista esté el día esté marcado en el calendario sin tener que hacer nada. Suponía que usando la variable del scope en el ng-model ya estaría, pero el caso es que no me está haciendo nada.

El código es muy básico:

```
<datepicker date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" date-week-start-day="1" ng-model="dt">
   <input ng-show = "false" name="day" type="text" class = "smallInputCrear" ng-model="dt">
</datepicker>
```

y en el Controlador:

```
$scope.dt = new Date();
```

Estaría muy agradecido si alguien me pudiera echar una mano.
Gracias.

Comment: Comparte el link de documentacion de la directiva datepicker para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deduzco, por las lineas de código, que estas utilizando el componente de [angular-datepicker](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker/).
En la documentación indica que el ng-model hay que ponérselo al tag `<input>` no al `<datepicker>`. Tambien indica que para marcar un día por defecto, hay que usar date-set="{{date}}"

Comment: Hola gracias, estoy utilizando este: https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker

Comment: y a parte de tener el ng-model duplicado (resuelto) he utilizado el date-set en el input añadiéndolo al código que indico arriba, pero sigue sin seleccionarme el dia actual. Como indica la documentación utilizando una variable diferente del ng-model

Comment: Controlador:
`$scope.date = new Date();
$scope.today = new Date();`
 HTML:
 `<datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd">
    <input ng-model="date" date-set="today" type="text"/>
</datepicker>`

Comment: El data-set va en la etiqueta datepicker y el ng-model en el input. HTML `<datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" date-set="{{today|date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"> <input  ng-model="date" type="text"/> </datepicker>`

Comment: Muchas gracias Naimad, aunque sigue sin marcarme el dia actual. La fecha la coje bien porque me aparece en el input, y utilizo variables distintas, pero nada. Se que debe ser alguna tontería pero no la encuentro.

Answer (score 1):

El código correcto sería el siguiente, en el **controlador**:

```
$scope.date = new Date();
```

y en el **HTML**:

```
<datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd">
    <input ng-model="date" type="text"/>
</datepicker>
```

Comment: Con ese código se muestra el día actual en una línia en la parte superior pero no aparece el calendario con el dia actual seleccionado.

Answer (score 0):

Hola dejo este ejemplo que me funciono en angular 7.

```
 //------------------------------file:filtro.ts--------------------

 export interface filtro {
     FechaDesde?: string; 
    FechaHasta?: string  
  }


            //-------------------------------file:componente.ts--------------------------

            import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
            import { filtro } from 'src/app/models/filtro';

            @Component({
              selector: 'app-datos-form',
              templateUrl: './datos-form.component.html',
              styleUrls: ['./datos-form.component.css']
            })

            export class DatosFormComponent implements OnInit {

              Filtro: filtro = {
                FechaDesde: "", 
                FechaHasta: "" 
              };

              constructor() { }

              ngOnInit() {

                //FechaDesde
                var f1 = new Date();
                let fd = this.formatDate(f1);
                this.Filtro.FechaDesde= fd;
                //FechaHasta
                this.Filtro.FechaHasta= fd;

              }


              formatDate(date : Date): string {
                //dia
                var d = date.getDate();d++;
                var d2 ="";
                if (d<10){
                  d2 = "0" + d;
                }else{
                  d2 = "" + d;
                }
                //mes
                var m = date.getMonth();m++;
                var m2 ="";
                if (m<10){
                  m2 = "0" + m;
                }else{
                  m2 = "" + m;
                }
                //año
                var y = date.getFullYear();

                //fecha format string yyyy-mm--dd
                var f =  y + "-" + m2 + "-" + d2
                console.log(f);
                //return `${d}-${m}-${y}`;
                return f;
                //return "2019-05-03";
              }
            }

            ------------------------------html------------------------------
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="dateDesde">Desde</label>
                        <input id="dateDesde" name ="dateDesde" type="date" class="form-control col-sm-3"
                        [(ngModel)]="Filtro.FechaDesde" date='dd-MM-yyyy'>

                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="dateHasta">Hasta</label>
                        <input id="dateHasta" name ="dateHasta" type="date" class="form-control col-sm-3"
                        [(ngModel)]="Filtro.FechaHasta" date='dd-MM-yyyy'>
                      </div>   
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], edita y explica tu respuesta pues aportar solo con código se considera de baja calidad